# Rigging issue with walk cycle

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I've created a walk cycle with this Borg character.  The character was linked in the cycle file from it's original 'Borg 8' file.

All was fine, then i did some alterations to the arms in the original file.  Now his left arm seems to be duplicated, rather than mirrored, although it is still swinging in the correct contrary motion in relation to the right arm.

I posed the walk cycle key frames using the shift+ctrl+v method (i.e. posing one side of the rig then copy/pasting the inverse pose to the other side).

Now this copy paste function doesn't seem to work either.  Any help with matter would be gratefully received...i'm supposed to be animating this for commercial purposes.

Many thanks in advance
Chamine

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40557544/Borg8.blend
https://www.dropbox.com/s/l4mypqucjmgz0br/Walk%20cycle%204.blend?dl=0

Comment: Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for any blend uploads.